# How to remove decimals from python django code

Tags: python, django

This is the code:

```
def adprice(self):
    return self.get_ad().attr[price_net]
```

`price_net` has 2 decimals, but I don't want them to show. How can I remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to:

```
def adprice(self):
    return self.get_ad().attr[int(price_net)]
```

It should work.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but perhaps someone felt an explanation of *why* your code would work?